# Puppeteer. What is waitForNavigation waiting for?

Tags: puppeteer

What "navigation" is `waitForNavigation` waiting for?

The websites navigation? The browsers refresh icon "navigation" to finish spinning?

Or is this just a awkwardly worded method that should be named `waitForBrowserToLoad`?

---

But, when I use it, like so:

`await this.page.waitForNavigation();`

The page DOES finish loading.

And yet it never resolves. I'm not sure why.

What is `waitForNavigation` waiting for?

```
async function beforeScrape(page) {
  //code gets this far
  await this.page.waitForNavigation();
  //never resolves
  await page.click(".table-header");
}
```

Comment: Please, show how you're using this method in the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Documentation](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pagewaitfornavigationoptions) says:

> [page.waitForNavigation] resolves when the page navigates to a new URL or reloads. It is useful for when you run code which will indirectly cause the page to navigate.

For example you fill a form and the click "Submit" button, after which a new page is shown with results. This way you can wait until the new page loaded:

```
await Promise.all([
  page.waitForNavigation(),
  page.click('input[type=submit]'),
]);
```

If you instruct the script to wait for navigation, but do not cause one, it will just sit there waiting until timing out.